# how to be warned if terminal has sudo privileges and also show how much time is left?

Tags: sudo

How to see in the terminal that you have sudo privileges? (so knowing I have these privileges, I can just type `sudo -k`) It would be better to not add too much information into the terminal also, just some kind of simple and small alert!

**REMAINING TIME IS IMPOSSIBLE, right?**

Also, how to see how much time I still have with those privileges on that specific terminal? (so I can just let it end instead of typing `sudo -k`). I think that remaining time could show up each time I press Enter key.

**EDIT: I researched more and found that `/var/lib/sudo/$USER/$nPts` (where $nPts is current terminal pts as of `ps -p $$`) has its timestamp updated everytime a sudo command is issued, and it is only accessible if you use a sudo command, so the remaining time will always be the configured one...**

PS.: Alternatively to that, I tried `alias sudo='sudo -k'` but I dislike having to type the password for every command... And also, this `alias sudos='sudo -k'` (or `alias ssudo='sudo -k'`, good if you typed a long line, just press Home and type 's') works if you only want to issue one command by typing `sudos`. But I still miss to know when I have normal sudo privileges to know I need to act...

Comment: Why was this down-voted? Although this isn't the clearest post, the title question still seems like a valid question to me (and a pretty useful question, at that)

Comment: could you say what could be clarified? my unedited initial post was 3 times bigger and I cleared it a lot to make it more concise :)

Comment: I think it was just late - I've re-read it, and it makes more sense.

Answer (score 5):

**[I still would like to know if there is a better answear.]**

I found a way that works, and the prompt will be kept on a single line:

at the end of your `~/.bashrc` add this:

```
function FUNCsudoOn() { 
    if sudo -n uptime 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null; then 
        echo -ne "\E[0m\E[93m\E[41m\E[1m\E[5m SUDO \E[0m"; 
        #echo #without newline, the terminal seems to bugout with lines that are too big... discomment this if you find any problems...
    fi; 
}
function FUNCpromptCommand () { 
    FUNCsudoOn
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND=FUNCpromptCommand
#export PS1="\`FUNCsudoOn\`$PS1" #this also works, use instead of PROMPT_COMMAND
```

**EDIT: I found that `sudo -n uptime` will update the sudo timeout, so everytime you hit the Enter key, that sudo time will be updated... That makes knowing the remaining time useless, as it will always be the configured one, defaulting to 15min...**

and to find the best colors formatting for you taste you can use [ScriptEchoColor](http://scriptechocolor.sourceforge.net/) with `--escapedchars` option like:

```
echoc --escapedchars "@{nRlyo} SUDO " #that outputs below...
echo -e "\E[0m\E[93m\E[41m\E[1m\E[5m SUDO \E[0m"
```

to just stop the blinking remove `\E[5m` like in `\E[0m\E[93m\E[41m\E[1m SUDO \E[0m`

Answer (score 4):

Your terminal doesn't "have sudo privileges", unless you do something silly like `sudo bash` **DON'T DO THIS!**

All you have to do to "have normal sudo privileges" is to refrain from typing `sudo` in front of the command.

`/usr/bin/id` is a good way to see what `sudo` does. For example:

```
id -a        # returns my UID info
sudo id -a   # returns root's info
id -a        # me again
sudo id -a   # root again
```

The `sudo` man page says "The sudoers policy caches credentials for 15 minutes, unless overridden in sudoers(5)". What this means is that, by default, if you issue a `sudo` command (and enter your password),then wait 14.9 minutes before issuing a second `sudo` command, you won't have to enter your password again. If you wait 15.1 minutes, you will have to re-enter the password. `sudo -k` simply expires the 15 minute timer immediately. The only use I can see for `sudo -k` is if you're about to yield your unlocked terminal to someone you don't trust with `UID 0`.

Comment: You said "refrain from typing `sudo` in front of the command". But if I want to check my firewall rules with `iptables -L` it wont work unless I type `sudo iptables -L`. My point is, how can we actually avoid using sudo?

Comment: Also, about the remaining time, I want to know how much time is left each time I press Enter key on terminal. About `sudo -k`, I am worried about crackers trying to remotely access my machine (I dont really know if they can do it anyway...), or in case I leave my machine open without locking it up for a few moments... well, the real point is that: I want to do it this way! I dont care having to type `sudo -k` and my password again later as many times I need to, I feel good when I do it this way! :)

Comment: "Avoid using sudo"? Sudo was the solution to distributing the root password, making binaries setuid, or using `/bin/su`. Are you sure you want to discard it?    

"Remotely access my machine..." and, I suppose, take over `/proc/YourPID/fd/{0,1,2}`. No. If your machine is remotely accessed, the Bad Guy has easier ways to UID 0. You should increase your Linux-foo prior to this level of concern.

Comment: Sorry for the rant, it sounds like you should `alias k=/usr/bin/sudo -k`, replace the `sudo` command with an alias or bash function that wraps the call to `/usr/bin/sudo` with `/usr/bin/touch $HOME/tmp/$$/sudotime`, and finally, add something to print ${{ time(now) - time($HOME/tmp/$$/sudotime) )) in your Bash prompt. Not trivial, but if it will make you feel good, go for it.

Comment: that is interesting, I would also log when the attempt happened, or even better, shutdown any network communication, cool! but even if I hide `sudo` with an alias to any random word, they could still type `/usr/bin/sudo` instead of `sudo` and it would still work as sudo does :(. Anyway I like the idea.. I wonder if I change the real `/usr/bin/sudo` it will break something other than all my scripts that use it.. even if I do so, they could, by reading the scripts, guess what sudo became..

Comment: I just thought, to each sudo attempt, there could have an usb stick with finger print recognition. And a display showing some more info like the command and terminal pts...

Comment: mmm... move `/usr/bin/sudo` to somewhere else... make it behave like it is not sudo (like requiring some more keys to be pressed after a fake message and timeout), and... put the scripts there too may be... sounds good? because I like it! (if it dont break the system..)

Comment: Why not `sudo bash`?  This saves the typing of `sudo` before every command in a long series of commands requiring root privileges.  Any process running with `sudo` is uid=0, so functionally it is the same.  The only downside I can think of is that it encourages running some processes as `root` when it isn't necessary because you're already at a `root` terminal.  But this is user error.  Why would you say not to use `sudo bash`?

Comment: I'm not saying "hide sudo". The "alias k=/usr/bin/sudo -k" just makes it easier for you to type. `sudo somecommand;k` or `sudo somecommand;sudo -k` and your credentials are gone. If you define a shell function, or have $HOME/bin early in your $PATH, you can let yourself intercept sudo commands without hiding `/usr/bin/sudo`. Why not `sudo bash`? 1: Commands won't be logged, like `sudo cmd1;sudo cmd2` will be; 2:It's easier to forget that you're root and do something both powerful and stupid. By typing the 5 characters "sudo " before a powerful command I can somethimes avoid the stupid part.

Comment: @waltinator good idea the `$HOME/bin` early on path so I can protect against access attempts thru my normal user and not mess the system! indeed, I remember long ago sometimes I left a shell with root privileges for hours... then appeared the "red" terminal borders if you were root there, but it didnt help much... btw I am using `alias ssudo='sudo -k'` also, as it help to quickly press home key and add 's' to beggining of sudo :)

Comment: I've seen old root shells when I've been doing security audits. Scary! I've done some more inspection of the `sudo` source, and, to access the token (to see how much time is left), you'd have to be UID 0. If you use `sudo` to find hot how much time is left, that would start the timer all over again.